# Why after bluring my page I'm loosing quality of my pictures?

Tags: android, css, animation

I am making a hybrid app and I have a page with some pictures and always after adding this animation:

```
.blur { 
    animation-name: bluring!important;
    animation-duration: 0.5s;
    }

@keyframes bluring {
    0% {filter: blur(0px);}
    100% {filter: blur(27px);}
    }
```

using jquery:

```
$('#my_pic, #another_pic').addClass('animated blur');
```

having a button which turns it back

```
$( '#my_button' ).click(function() {
$('#my_pic, #another_pic').removeClass('animated blur');
$('#my_pic, #another_pic').addClass('animated unblur');   
});
```

BTW

```
.unblur {
    animation-name: unbluring;
    animation-duration: 0.5s;
}

@keyframes unbluring {
    0% {filter: blur(27px);}
    100% {filter: blur(0px);}
}
```

quality of my pictures decreases. Why? This happens on my phone (android). And on my tablet (android) whole page during the blur zooms in the background. But on my tablet I don't lose quality. Can anyone help?

Before:[image]

After:[image]

Comment: what you mean by "quality"  ? is now pixelated ? or is just that just see different the blur effect on each browser and device

Comment: Is now pixelated, exactly.

Comment: Does the blur add and the remove itself again or do you have to manually remove the blur?

Comment: I do it manually clicking on the button.